# What is happening behind @Retention in java 1.5

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to understand the retention policy from Java 1.5. But not getting a clear picture.

As [per JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html),

- `CLASS` - Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the
  compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time.
- `RUNTIME` - Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the
  compiler and retained by the VM at run time,so they may be read
  reflectively.
- `SOURCE` - Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler

1. what does it mean by "discarded"?
2. Is it like the class file will not have the particular annotated element in it by marking it with SOURCE?

Comment: "Thrown out". "Not included in". Imagine some document-processing tools that look at the source files only. Or perhaps a particular compiler might use them for compile-time hints ..

Answer (score 6):

`SOURCE` annotations are only present in the source file.

When the compiler "discards" the annotation, it is essentially ignoring that the annotation even exists.  Source annotations basically serve the same purpose as commenting code.

Answer (score 3):

The annotated *element* is not affected.

`@Retention` is what you'd call a meta-annotation: it *only* applies to *other annotation interfaces*. As such it also *only*  affects the *annotation* it is applied to.

For example if you had an annotation named `@Foo` that is *itself* annotated with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)`, then the `@Foo` annotation (on another element) would be parsed by the compiler, but *not* stored in the resulting `.class` file (so if you'd ask the runtime if the element had the `@Foo` annotation, you'd get a negative answer).

This can be useful if you use an annotation purely for documentation purposes or if you want to handle it with annotation processing (during the compile step).

Comment: thanks for your response.. So like in the above example, My @Foo annotation interface and its method declarations will not be there in the compiled class file?. Because, i created one such annotation interface and marked it with SOURCE. When I decompile the .class file of that interface , I still find the interface and its methods..??...

Comment: And Moreover, I am not able to differentiate anything in the class file when I use the other two constants as well...RUNTIME and CLASS..

Answer (score 1):

In the Java programming language, annotations can be used as a special form of syntactic metadata in the source code.
Classes, methods, variables, parameters and packages may be annotated. The annotations can be embedded in class files generated by the compiler and may be RETAINED by the Java virtual machine and thus influence the run-time behaviour of an application.

A retention policy determines at what point annotation should be discarded.
Annotation with retention policy RUNTIME will be available to the JVM through runtime.